# R language: mean() na.rm still returns NA

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the mean of a column in a file and there are a bunch of `NULL` hidden inside the column. I inpute
`mean(scoobydoo$engagement,na.rm = TRUE)`,
but it returns

```
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(scoobydoo$engagement, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

`scoobydoo` is the name of the dataset and `engagement` is the column name. What's wrong?

Comment: What does `str(scoobydoo)` show you as the type of variable for `engagement` ? Most likely it was read in as type character, hence "not numeric or logical". You need to deal with the NULL values (convert them to NA) when you read in the file.

Comment: @neilfws OK, I see. It actually returns ```chr [1:603]```. So I need to convert them into numericals first. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are working with [this CSV file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2021/2021-07-13/scoobydoo.csv).

Rather than converting to numeric after reading in the data, you can specify which values should be treated as NA:

```
library(readr)

scoobydoo <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2021/2021-07-13/scoobydoo.csv", 
                      na = c("", "NA", "NULL"))
```

Base `read.csv` has a similar argument, `na.strings =` .

Comment: also available in base R: `scoobydoo <- read.csv("...", na.strings = c("", "NA", "NULL"))`